# Strange behavior of generics

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I want to implement some example of [Interpreter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern)
And met some trouble with code example.

I want to pass to method `List` of child elements using parent reference:

Here is a code snippet from *main()*:

```
GoodPackage truck = new GoodPackage();
truck.setGoodsInside(new ArrayList<Goods>());
Bed bed = new Bed();
GoodPackage doubleTriplePackedBed = new GoodPackage();
doubleTriplePackedBed.setGoodsInside(Arrays.asList(new GoodPackage().setGoodsInside(Arrays.asList(bed))));
```

Other classes:

```
abstract class Goods {
    public abstract Integer interpret(CurrentPricesContext context);
}

class GoodPackage extends Goods {
    private List<? super Goods> goodsInside;

    @Override
    public Integer interpret(CurrentPricesContext context) {
        int totalSum = 0;
        for (Iterator<? super Goods> iter = goodsInside.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()) {
            Goods good = (Goods) iter.next();
            totalSum += good.interpret(context);
        }
        /*for (Goods goods : goodsInside) {
            totalSum += goods.interpret(context);
        }*/
        return totalSum;
    }

    public List<? super Goods> getGoodsInside() {
        return goodsInside;
    }

    public void setGoodsInside(List<? super Goods> goodsInside) {
        this.goodsInside = goodsInside;
    }
}

class Bed extends Goods {
    @Override
    public Integer interpret(CurrentPricesContext context) {
        int price = context.getPrice(GoodsInstances.BAD);
        System.out.printf("Bad: %d%n", price);
        return price;
    }
}
```

Issue is that:

```
  setGoodsInside (java.util.List<? super patterns.behavioral.interpreter.Goods>)   
  can't be applicable to java.util.List<patterns.behavioral.interpreter.Bed>
```

I couldn't figure out what I missed. Because the type of list is `List<? super Goods>`.

***How to solve this issue?***

Comment: It kind of looks like you meant extends almost everywhere you used super...

Comment: Also your for loop will skip every other element, which I don't think you want.

Comment: There is no need to waste everybody's bandwidth by posting an image of source code instead of the actual code itself: and this question has nothing to do with 'dynamic despatch'.

Comment: @user207421 with a long delay fixed that comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `X<? super Y>` is an object of type `X` that may consume objects of type `Y` (i.e. `Y` is the parameter type of methods of `X`). A `X<? extends Y>` is an object of type `X` that may produce objects of type `Y` (i.e. `Y` is the return type of methods of `X`).

So, a `List<? super Goods>` is a list where you can add any instance of `Goods`, which is `List<Goods>` or `List<Object>`. This do not includes `List<Bed>` because you can't add any instance of `Goods` there, just some (i.e. those who happens to be instances of the `Bed` subclass).

A `List<? extends Goods>` is a list from where you can retrieve `Goods`, which is `List<Goods>`, `List<GoodPackage>` or `List<Bed>`. Whatever is the item retrieved from the list, it will always be an instance of `Goods` (or some of its subclass).

So I think that you really wanted to use `List<? extends Goods>` instead of `List<? super Goods>`:

```
class GoodPackage extends Goods {
    private List<? extends Goods> goodsInside;

    @Override
    public Integer interpret(CurrentPricesContext context) {
        int totalSum = 0;
        for (Goods goods : goodsInside) {
            totalSum += goods.interpret(context);
        }
        return totalSum;
    }

    public List<? extends Goods> getGoodsInside() {
        return goodsInside;
    }

    public void setGoodsInside(List<? extends Goods> goodsInside) {
        this.goodsInside = goodsInside;
    }
}
```

And about this `for` loop:

```
    for (Iterator<? super Goods> iter = goodsInside.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()) {
        Goods good = (Goods) iter.next();
        totalSum += good.interpret(context);
    }
```

It has two problems:

- It will give a `ClassCastException` if you got a `List<Object>` with something that is not `Goods` inside (like a `String` or a `Cat`).
- You are calling the `next()` method twice. This will result in it interpreting only the odd-numbered items and will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the list has an even number of elements.

The equivalent, without using the enhanced-for syntax would be this:

```
    for (Iterator<? extends Goods> iter = goodsInside.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Goods good = iter.next();
        totalSum += good.interpret(context);
    }
```